# Rails 7 vanilla-nested gem link to add item not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to use the vanilla-nested gem, with Rails 7, to add an item in a nested edit form. The link is not work and not action results.

I have tried to follow the example code in the gem test path for rails 7.

Here is the edit view:

activities/edit.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-2">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <br>
        <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Update Transaction</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<%= render "form", activity: @activity %>
```

The form partial:

activities/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <%= image_tag '16419114852474091540459891939039.jpeg', class: "main-image",
      width: "658", sizes: "(max-width: 767px) 96vw, (max-width: 991px) 354px, 460px", alt: ""
    %>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card-block px-2">
      <%= form_for activity do |form| %>
        

    <div class="row">
        <%= form.label :date_submitted, class: 'col-lg-3 text-right', style: "display: block" %>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          <%= form.date_field :date_submitted %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <%= form.label :transaction_date, class: 'control-label col-lg-3', style: "display: block" %>
       <div class="col-lg-2">
         <%= form.date_field :activity_date %>
       </div>
     </div>
     <br>

     <div>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-8">
           <h3>Transaction Items</h3>
           <%= link_to_add_nested(form, :items, '#items') do %>
            <span><span> Add Item</span></span>
           <% end %>
         </div>
       </div>
        <div id='items'>
            <%= form.fields_for :items do |sub_form| %>
              <%= render 'item_fields', form: sub_form  %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        </div>
       <div>
         <%= form.submit 'Save Update', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
       </div>
      <% end %>
      <br>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card-footer w-100 text-muted">
  <div>
    <%= link_to "Show this activity", @activity %> |
    <%= link_to "Back to activities", activities_path %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The fields partial:

activities/_item_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="item-fields">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= form.label :amount, style: "display: block" %>
      <%= form.text_field :item_amount %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <%= form.label :vendor, style: "display: block" %>
      <%= form.text_field :vendor %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= form.label :expense_category, style: "display: block" %>
      <%= form.select(:expense_category, @category_choices) %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <%= form.label :transaction_type, style: "display: block" %>
      <%= form.select(:transaction_type, @transaction_choices) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

The Items model

models/item.rb

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

The Activity model:

models/activity.rb

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, reject_if: :all_blank

  has_one_attached :activity_image

  validate :acceptable_image



  def acceptable_image
    return unless activity_image.attached?

    unless activity_image.byte_size <= 5.megabyte
      errors.add(:activity_image, "is too big")
    end

    acceptable_types = ["image/jpeg", "image/png"]
    unless acceptable_types.include?(activity_image.content_type)
      errors.add(:activity_image, "must be a JPEG or PNG")
    end
  end
end
```

The Activities controller

controllers/activities_controller.rb

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_activity, only: %i[ show edit update destroy add_item ]

  # GET /activities or /activities.json
  def index
    @activities = Activity.all
  end

  # GET /activities/1 or /activities/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /activities/new
  def new
    @activity = Activity.new
    @activity.items.build
  end

  # GET /activities/1/edit
  def edit
    set_transaction_choices
    set_category_choices
  end

  # POST /activities or /activities.json
  def create
    @activity = Activity.new(activity_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @activity.save
        format.html { redirect_to activity_url(@activity), notice: "Activity was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @activity }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /activities/1 or /activities/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @activity.update(activity_params)
        format.html { redirect_to activity_url(@activity), notice: "Activity was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @activity }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /activities/1 or /activities/1.json
  def destroy
    @activity.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to activities_url, notice: "Activity was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_activity
      @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def activity_params
      params.require(:activity).permit(:account_id, :user_id, :date_submitted,
        :activity_date, :reviewed, :finalized, :notes, :emailed_question,
          items_attributes: [ :id, :item_amount, :vendor,
            :expense_category, :transaction_type])
    end

    def set_transaction_choices
      @transaction_choices = [["Expense", 'expense'], ["Revenue", 'revenue']]
    end

    def set_category_choices
      @category_choices = ['Fuel', 'Tolls',
      'Repairs and Maintance', 'Plates', 'Truck Insurance',
      'Cell Phone', 'Internet', 'Satellite', 'Perdiem Days',
      'Office Supplies', 'Professional Services',
      'Other expenses', 'Liability Insurnace', 'Health Insurnace',
      'Truck Supplies and Equipment',
      'Working Clothes and Gear', 'Lease and Rental Fees',
      'Taxes and Licenses', 'Travel Expenses',
      'Contract Wages', 'Revenue',
      'Marketing Fees', 'Subscriptions',
      'Software' ]
      @category_choices.sort!
    end
end
```

The Items controller

controllers/items_controller.rb

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /items or /items.json
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  # GET /items/1 or /items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /items/new
  def new
  end

  # GET /items/1/edit
  def edit
  end


  def add_item
    @act = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
    @act.items.create(
      activity: @act
    )
  end


  # POST /items or /items.json
  # POST /items or /items.json
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_activity_path(activity_id), notice: "Item was successfully created." }
        #format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        #format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1 or /items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to item_url(@item), notice: "Item was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1 or /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_url, notice: "Item was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:activity_id, :item_amount, :vendor, :expense_category, :transaction_type)
    end

end
```

The application.js file:

app/javascript/application.js

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"

import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"

import "custom/main"

import "vanilla-nested";
```

the importmap.rb

config/importmap.rb

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true

pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "trix"

pin "@rails/actiontext", to: "actiontext.js"

pin "vanilla-nested", to: "vanilla_nested.js", preload: true

pin_all_from "app/javascript/custom", under: "custom"
```

Comment: Hi, first of all I see you are using both an app/javascript/application.js file (webpacker I guess?) and importamps, you don't need both, you shouldn't have both since things may conflict. Second, is there any error anywhere? the terminal where rails is running? the browser's devtools console? Finally, can you try using the code directly from github? the latest code has some refactor that may fix some issues with rails 7 https://github.com/arielj/vanilla-nested#installation check the github related install instructions

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: A correction on my previous comment (I don't have much experience with importmaps), I think you are using just importmaps so ignore my first point! we still need to see if there's any error somewhere

Comment: I tried to use the code straight from github from the rails 7 example. Nothing happens in the rails terminal window or the browser tools console either.   Is it an issue that I am trying to issue Vanilla-nested in an edit/update view?

Comment: If nothing shows up anywhere then something is wrong with the javascript. I see you seem to have the same configuration I have in the rails 7 test app https://github.com/arielj/vanilla-nested/tree/main/test/VanillaNestedTestRails7, do you see the vanilla_nested.js file loading in the network tab in dev tools? do you see the `import` statement in the application.js if you open it in dev tools?

Comment: Yes vanilla-nested is loaded in the network tab and imported.  Is there an issue that the view is for an update form vs. a create form?

Comment: it shouldn't be an issue, do you have your code uploaded somewhere I can look? please remember to tag me or I don't receive notifications